# Azure IoT File Upload

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-sdk, azure-iot-hub-device-management

I have successfully used [this feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-file-upload) to upload files to a storage container in Azure blob storage. I wanted to ask if this form of file upload has the same integrity checks using MD5 hash as there is with normal blob storage uploading. This [link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsazurestorage/2011/02/17/windows-azure-blob-md5-overview/) describes that feature for blob storage. Also, it seems this check is optional, if so, is there a way for me to ensure that this happens when I upload from my iot device using the **azure-iot-sdk**'s.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested this issue with Azure IoT SDK for CSharp. When uploading the file to azure iot hub, I uses fiddler to catch the http request. Actually, the headers in the request contains `Content-MD5`. So if you use Azure IoT SDK for CSharp, you need not to check the option for MD5. And you can refer to the method **UploadFromStreamAsync** in [Microsoft Azure Storage SDK for .NET](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net), this method is called when upload file via **UploadFromStreamAsync** method.

[image]

**Update:**

MD5 cannot be calculated for an existing blob because it would require reading the existing data. Please disable storeBlobContentMD5.

Comment: Is this the same for the c SDK?

Comment: No, it is different with C SDK. You can run the sample iothub_client_sample_upload_to_blob and then check the content-md5. You need to implement that yourself.

Comment: @radish25, is any other question about that? Feel free let me know.